# Running an Nsight Systems report python script independently

Tags: python, python-3.x, cuda, syntax-error, nsight-systems

I've tweaked a copy of one of the Nsight Systems report scripts (gpukernsum), and I now want to run it myself. So, I write:

```
./gpukernsum.py report.sqlite
```

This doesn't work; I get:

```
ERROR: Script 'gpukernsum.py' encountered an internal error.

$ ./gpukernsum.py report.sqlite
  File "./gpukernsum.py", line 40
    """
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I know this is because `f"""whatever"""` is Python-3 syntax, so I change the script's hash-bang line from:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

to:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
```

and now I get:

```
$ ./gpukernsum.py report.sqlite
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/./gpukernsum.py", line 7, in <module>
    import nsysstats
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'nsysstats'
```

So I added the relevant directory to the lookup path:

```
export PYTHONPATH="$PYTHONPATH:/opt/nvidia/nsight-systems/2022.1.1/host-linux-x64/python/lib"
```

and now I get:

```
$ ./gpukernsum.py report.sqlite
near "WITH": syntax error
```

... and I'm stuck. The relevant area of the code is:

```
    and not a percentage of the application wall or CPU execution time.
"""

    query_stub = """
WITH
    summary AS (
        SELECT
            coalesce({NAME_COL_NAME}, demangledName) AS nameId,
```

i.e. the "WITH" is part of a string literal which is an SQL query. So, what's the problem? Is Python complaining? Is sqlite complaining?

Note:

- Nsight Systems 2022.1.1
- CentOS 7
- I'm using the original gpukernsum.py code - I have not made any changes to it (other than as described above).
- My system has Python 3.9.1 for `python3`.

Comment: Could you share a reproducible example of the code?

Comment: @zois: It's the gpukernsum.py script of Nsight Systems 2022.1.1 ...

Comment: So, I have a workaround answer - which I can't post since the question is closed: Nsight Systems bundles its own version of Python. If you force its use, and set the PYTHONPATH as described in my question, then the script will work.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround answer:

Nsight Systems bundles its own version of Python, with `lib` and `bin` directories.

If you run your script with this specific version, having set `PYTHONPATH` as described in your question - then the script will work. It's what Nsight itself does, after all.